# Including external libraries in cpack output

Tags: c++, opengl, cmake, cpack

Im currently working on a cmake project which is making use of external libraries which are being imported through the find_package function. My question revolves around cpack and how I am supposed to go about adding the found packages into the cpack output. For example if I use this

```
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

add_executable(Example_App MACOSX_BUNDLE src/main.cpp)

target_include_directories(Example_App SYSTEM PUBLIC ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries(Example_App PUBLIC ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})

install(TARGETS Example_App
    BUNDLE DESTINATION "."
    RUNTIME DESTINATION bin)
```

If I then run cmake .. followed by make and make package my output from cpack (I can include an example of my cpack code if needed too) would then be.
ExampleApp-linux.tar.bz2

```
- bin
-- Example_App
- Share
-- Resource files
```

Rather than something like:

```
- bin
-- Example_App
- Lib
-- OpenGL.a
- Share
-- Resource files
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to explicitly add an install rule for the external project libraries.

For example:

```
install(FILES ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION bin COMPONENT RuntimeLibraries
  LIBRARY DESTINATION bin COMPONENT RuntimeLibraries
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION Lib COMPONENT Development
  )
```

Or you could use a specific library reference like `${OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY}` instead of `${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}`. See [Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake) for more details.