# How do you deploy/package a CMake project with Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I'm currently working on a small CMake project with visual studio and I'm wanting to distribute my current build but I have no clue how to, when testing the app on another system it would error saying what I'm guessing were runtime dll's that were missing. I can't find anything online about it, and the official CMake tutorial didn't work for me. Does anyone know a way to do this?

Comment: Learn about CPack. I use the NSIS generator on windows / msvc since 2008 on all my work projects but there are other options like WIX.

Comment: Make sure they have the VC++ runtime installed. Also, make sure you aren't sending them debug builds (you could, but you'd need debug libraries for VC++ then too)

Comment: Make sure you built the project in a non-debug configuration. The debug runtime is probably not available on the target system.

Comment: Im using the default Release x64 build for the ones i'm sending.
Also for the VC++ runtime I'm struggling to find out how to get the VC++ runtime as something that is part of the app, I would prefer if they just had to download 1 thing to be able to run the app.

Comment: They either need to have the runtimes already installed, or you can package into an installer. I think there might be a way to statically link, instead of dynamically, but I've never done that against the VC++ runtimes.

Comment: Installing the runtime DLLs is a one-time thing, done for the first C++ app installed. So, some users will have them already, the others can get it from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio the redistributable package should be in your compiler's folders. You can use CPack to create an installer and install the redistributable as a component of the install.

Comment: Although there are newer methods I use a method similar to this: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577979/how-to-get-location-of-needed-runtime-libraries-for-msvc/13579615#13579615](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13577979/how-to-get-location-of-needed-runtime-libraries-for-msvc/13579615#13579615)

Comment: Related to newer method: [https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.html](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.html)

Comment: Also: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70728518/how-can-i-make-cpack-include-3rd-party-dlls-into-the-installer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70728518/how-can-i-make-cpack-include-3rd-party-dlls-into-the-installer)

Comment: @BoP What I'm talking about is that I'm wanting the DLLs as part of the app it's self, making it possible to be a portable app that is just within a ZIP or something. Like a whole in one package. I don't think its possible to do that with the VC++ installer

Comment: With an installer you have to install it somewhere to run. It's not a portable app.

Comment: ***What I'm talking about is that I'm wanting the DLLs as part of the app it's self, making it possible to be a portable app that is just within a ZIP or something*** You probably want to get rid of the dlls then and replace with static libraries and have static runtime. Creating a portable app itself is not something CMake solves for you. You will probably have to implement that yourself depending on your project complexity of your project and dependencies this could be easy or it could be impossible.

Comment: It's a tradeoff, as usual, If you install the runtime separately it will receive security fixes from Windows Update. If you do a static link, or just copy the DLLs with the program, it will not. And, like I said, it is a one time thing for a user - any program written with VC++ since 2015 uses the same runtime. So high odds it is already present.

Comment: @BoP The reason I was wanting them to be "part of the app" is that I am wanting it to be able to run on school computers or business computers where the user is unable to install the VC++ libraries. I have tested this on my school's computers and it wouldn't run because they don't have the libraries installed. My target aren't people who use CPP apps regularly. The reason I'm wanting to be able to do this is that I want to be able to use my app on almost any computer without any "setup"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like you have been told in the comments, the proper way to distribute an application on Windows is to use VC redistributable package. But if one wants to create an independent "bundle" CMake can help with it. It has [a module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/InstallRequiredSystemLibraries.html) which helps to bring the necessary dlls wherever needed. You need to understand and plan how your resulting bundle will look like and adapt the paths accordingly. I will just show you how to bring the dlls to the current binary directory with the help of the said module:

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
include(InstallRequiredSystemLibraries)
```

These 2 lines will make sure that you have an install target by building which the dlls required will be copied (installed) to the `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` path. That would be your start from which you can proceed further with any customization you need to make.

Comment: Thanks! I'd figured out how to copy the DLLs from the Visual Studio install directory but this will be more stable and integrated.